# OPL CPLEX Syntax Problem with Array of Tuple

Tags: cplex, opl

This is .mod (model file)

```
tuple TDayPair{
  string day1;
  string day2;
}

{TDayPair} DAYS={<"Mon","Tue">,<"Thurs","Fri">};
int a[DAYS]= ...;
execute {
  writeln(a[<"Mon","Tue">]); //<--it gives syntax error here
}
```

This is .dat (data file)

```
a = #[
  <"Mon","Tue">:1,
  <"Thurs","Fri">:2,
]#;
```

It gives syntax error at the model file at `writeln(a[<"Mon","Tue">]);` what's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```
tuple TDayPair{
  string day1;
  string day2;
}

{TDayPair} DAYS={<"Mon","Tue">,<"Thurs","Fri">};
int a[DAYS]= ...;
execute {
  writeln(a[DAYS.find("Mon","Tue")]); //<--it gives syntax error here
}
```

You will get

```
1
```

OPL Modeling language is not the same as the [OPL Javascript language](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-within-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/) that helps with preprocessing, postprocessing and flow control.